# Why are there two Standard Serial over Bluetooth links in HC-05?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, serial-port, hc-05, com-port

I'm testing the HC-05 Bluetooth device and it works well using just one of two available "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link".
I would like to know the purpose of another "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link" as it's working well using just one?

[image: Standard Serial over Bluetooth link]
Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: One port is the incoming port and the other one is the outgoing port.